# URL Rewrite On Linux & Windows?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm making changes to some software.

What I would like to do is change part of the url. In all of the urls in my site, there is "index.php" in it. Example: "domain.com/index.php?action=area". I would like to change "index.php" to "view". Example: "domain.com/view?action=area".

From what I understand, this can be changed via htaccess. Although, htaccess is only for linux, correct? What about windows? How can this be done for both linux & windows?

Comment: Maybe it is because I don't understand the question, but I think you should explain more. Is it only for access from your computer to the domain?

Comment: it's a piece of forum software people can install on a linux or windows server. I was wondering if there was a mod_rewrite for windows? I am unfamiliar with using htaccess for re-writing URL's in the browser. Windows doesn't support htaccess correct? What would I put in my htaccess to change "index.php" to "view", and what about windows?

Comment: I'm looking at a site now that says windows server(IIS) does use htaccess. Is that true?

Comment: mod_rewrite for Apache works on both Linux & Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **mod_rewrite** that an Apache module. It works under Linux and Windows as long as you're using Apache (on windows, it may be referred to as ["Wamp"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP), though Apache can also be installed by itself).

If you are using IIS, there's a [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module that behaves similar to Apache's mod_rewrite. The syntax and sometimes the behavior of the rewrite engine isn't exactly the same as in Apache, so for simple things this should be fine.

You could also try to re-implement your Apache rewrite rules to use IIS's webconfig. There's [some tools for doing this](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig).

The mod_rewrite rules in question would look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?view$ /index.php [L]
```

Pretty simple.

Comment: I've placed a .htaccess file with the contents above at my forum root, but doesn't seem to work. I know mod_rewrite is enabled on my apache server.